# CUDA device pointers

Tags: c, cuda

Quick question about the standard CUDA memory allocation model:

```
double* x_device;
cudaMalloc(&x_device,myArraySize);
```

The variable `x_device` is a pointer-to-double.  After I call cudaMalloc, does x_device now point to a memory location *on the cuda device*?  So, in other words, `*x_device` would result in a segfault because we can't directly access device memory from the host.

Incidental question, the compiler doesn't complain that I don't use `(void**)&x_device`, is this required?  I sometimes see it in examples, sometimes not.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you cannot rely on a getting segfault when dereferencing device pointer on host. Results are undefined, but segfault is not guaranteed. You simply should never do that (dereferencing device pointer in the host code) regardless of result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right: `cudaMalloc` allocates memory on the device. You can't use this pointer directly on the host, but only as argument to functions like `cudaMemcpy`, and as arguments to kernel calls.

More recent CUDA versions support unified memory addressing, there you can use `cudaMallocManaged` to allocate device memory, and access it on the host directly via the device pointer.

For the second question: C++ doesn't allow implicit casts between pointer types, so there leaving out the explicit cast `(void**)&x_device` will result in a compiler error.

Comment: I don't think the answer to second question is completely right. The reason is that there is a template version of `cudaMalloc` declared in `cuda_runtime.h` which automatically casts any type of pointer passed to it into `void**`. When calling `cudaMalloc(&x_device,myArraySize);`, a function definition with following signature is generated by the compiler: `cudaMalloc(double**, size_t)`. Thats why there is no compiler error.